# create ionic labels dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ionic2

I'm trying  to   create  ion-labels  dynamically  in IONIC2.

I  can achieve  this  in JavaScript/Typescript  by  the following  code  using  HTML DOM

```
  var iDiv = document.createElement('input');
     iDiv.id="lbl2";
iDiv.setAttribute("type","text");
iDiv.setAttribute("style", "background-color: transparent;");
iDiv.setAttribute('width','400px')
iDiv.setAttribute('height','1000px')
 iDiv.setAttribute("value","");
iDiv.setAttribute("placeholder","Label2 placeholder");
document.getElementById('billerdiv').appendChild(iDiv);
```

**The  Above  code  creates Basic HTML  INPUT...**
Look  and  feel is  not  Upto ionic  Ion-label...

To  create ion-label and  ion-input  at HTML  side..  we  will  follow.

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Username</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
```

how  to  create this  dynamically in  JavaScript/Typescript.??

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that in order to do that, you will have to create the html markup that Ionic generates when you add that html code to your page. So when you add

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Username</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

in your page, after being rendered, that code is then transformed into:

```
<ion-item class="item item-input">
    <div class="item-inner">
        <div class="input-wrapper">
            <ion-label id="lbl-0">Username</ion-label>
            <!--template bindings={}-->
            <ion-input type="text">
                <input class="text-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" type="text" placeholder="" aria-labelledby="lbl-0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off">
                <!--template bindings={}-->
                <button class="text-input-clear-icon button button-clear" clear="" type="button" hidden=""><span class="button-inner"></span>
                    <ion-button-effect></ion-button-effect>
                </button>
                <!--template bindings={}-->
            </ion-input>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ion-button-effect></ion-button-effect>
</ion-item>
```

So creating that markup using `document.createElement('ion-item');` and then setting classes (with `element.className = ...;`) and appending childs (with `element.appendChild(anotherElement);`, even though is possible, will be a nightmare.

May I ask why do you need to create this labels dinamically? Maybe we can find a way to do it by using `Angular 2` methods and we can avoid doing things this way.